# LuaLatex, how to use calibri font even in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, fontspec

I'm writing a letter in LuaLatex using the calibri font. To set up I use these commands:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{calibri}[Ligatures=TeX,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5},
  Path=fonts/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  BoldFont = *b,
  ItalicFont = *i,
  BoldItalicFont = *z]
```

The problem is that I need to use inline math mode and the "math" font clashes very bad with the text font:

[image]

Is there a way to force the font even in math mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but I have not installed Calibri font on my pc. I'd use the option
`\setmathfont{XITS Math}` for the math mode.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Calibri}[range={up/{latin,Latin,num}, 
    it/{latin,Latin,num}, 
    bfup/{latin,Latin,num}, 
    bfit/{latin,Latin,num},
    frak/{latin,Latin,num}}]
\begin{document}

\[ \mathbf{F}(x) = \int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x^2} dx = 1 \]

\centering\textbf{F}(x) $\phi$ \textsc{SmallCaps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trying I found something that kind works:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{calibri}[Ligatures=TeX, SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}, Path=fonts/, Extension = .ttf, UprightFont = calibri, BoldFont = calibrib, ItalicFont = calibrii, BoldItalicFont = calibriz]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{calibri}[
    range={up/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}, 
    it/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}, 
    bfup/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}, 
    bfit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num},
    frak/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}},
    Path=fonts/, Extension=.ttf, UprightFont = calibri, BoldFont = calibrib, ItalicFont = calibrii, BoldItalicFont = calibriz
    ]
\DeclareMathOperator{\uphi}{\symbol{"03C6}}
```

But it's very unreliable. I need to load XITS Math for the symbols since a lot of them are missing in calibri, \mathbf does not work with a lot of character.

I would not feel confident to use this solution on a large scale document, seems kinda buggy.